# Problema inserción Hibernate+JSF+MYSQL Tablas relacionadas

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jsf, hibernate

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para el instituto Utilizando **Hibernate 4.3** + **netbeans 8.2** + **JSF 2.2** y **MYSQL**, el tema básicamente es una aplicación que crea notas(anotaciones), logré construir el login , y la autenticación el registro de usuarios y demás.

EL PROBLEMA surge cuando intento insertar una nota luego de haberme logueado con el usuario que ya cree, puesto que no logro hacer la inserción cabe mencionar que la tabla `user_id` es clave foránea con referencia a `ID_user` para poder relacionar las tablas y saber quien escribió cada nota pero cuando trato de ejecutar mi método no pasa nada en la BD(para registrar usuarios si)...

Por otro lado tengo un campo en la BD de tipo `Date` para almacenar la fecha en la cual se realizó la Nota en el sistema (tiene que ser la hora actual y no debe ser modificable por el usuario a menos que edite la nota y se haga un update de la fecha).

Pido que me orienten sobre como proceder con eso ya que encuentro muy poca información al respecto, me dicen que use el método Date, y otros Calendar y no se cual usar ni como. Espero me ayuden y de antemano MIL GRACIAS!

**NotesDaoImpl**

```
    package app.dao;
    import app.models.Notes;
    import app.models.Users;
    import java.util.List;
    import app.util.HibernateUtil;
    import org.hibernate.Query;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;


public class NotesDaoImpl implements notesDao{


@Override
public  List<Notes> getNotes() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void addNote(Notes newNote) {

    //Iniciamos Objeto de Session
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    //Creamos el objeto de tipo transaction para ejecutar la sentencia HQL

    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    //jecutamos el bloque try catch para la insercion
    try{
        session.merge(newNote);
        session.flush();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        transaction.rollback();

    }

}

@Override
public void deleteNote(Notes note) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void updateNote(Notes note) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}



}
```

**NotesBean.java**

```
 package app.beans;

import app.dao.notesDao;
import app.models.Notes;
import app.models.Users;
import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import app.dao.NotesDaoImpl;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;


@Named(value = "notesBean")
@ViewScoped
public class NotesBean implements Serializable {

private Notes note;
private List<Notes> nt;
private Users user;
private List<Users> people;
private Date date;

public NotesBean() {
    this.note = new Notes();
}

public Notes getNote() {
    return note;
}

public void setNote(Notes note) {
    this.note = note;
}

public List<Notes> getNt() {
    return nt;
}

public void setNt(List<Notes> nt) {
    this.nt = nt;
}

public Users getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(Users user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public List<Users> getPeople() {
    return people;
}

public void setPeople(List<Users> people) {
    this.people = people;
}


//Funcion para agregar Nueva Nota 
public void newNote(){
    notesDao notesDao = new NotesDaoImpl();
    notesDao.addNote(this.note);
    this.note = new Notes(); // inicializamos nuevamente para vaciar el contenido

}

}
```

**Users.hbm.xml**

```
    <class name="app.models.Users" table="users" catalog="notesapp" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="string">
        <column name="name" length="20" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="email" type="string">
        <column name="email" length="20" not-null="true" unique="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="password" type="string">
        <column name="password" length="20" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <set name="noteses" table="notes" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="user_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="app.models.Notes" />
    </set>
    <set name="noteses_1" table="notes" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="user_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="app.models.Notes" />
    </set>
</class>
```

**Notes.hbm.xml**

```
     <class name="app.models.Notes" table="notes" catalog="notesapp" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="users" class="app.models.Users" fetch="select">
        <column name="user_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="title" type="string">
        <column name="title" length="20" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="body" type="string">
        <column name="body" length="200" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="modified" type="date">
        <column name="modified" length="10" not-null="true" />
    </property>
</class>
```

Formulario para el **Registro de Notas** , no lo he terminado por el tema de que no sé como poner la Fecha y porque esos dos campos inicialmente tampoco me los inserta

```
   <h:form id="frmNewNote" >
                        <p:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin: 0 auto" >

                            <p:outputLabel value="Titulo: "/>
                            <p:inputText value="#{notesBean.note.title}" required="true" requiredMessage="El campo Título es Requerido"/>

                            <p:outputLabel value="Contenido: "/>
                            <p:inputTextarea rows="5" cols="30" value="#{notesBean.note.body}"  maxlength="100" counterTemplate="{0} characters remaining." autoResize="false" required="true" requiredMessage="El campo Contenido es Requerido" />



                            <p:commandButton value="Guardar" actionListener="#{notesBean.newNote()}" update=":frmNewNote"/>
```

**notesDao**

```
     package app.dao;
    import app.models.Notes;
    import java.util.List;


    public interface notesDao {

    public List<Notes> getNotes();

    public void addNote( Notes newNote);

    public void deleteNote( Notes note);

    public void updateNote(Notes note);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Al terminar la transacción, te falta invocar `session.close()`. Esto lo haces fuera del bloque try.

```
@Override
public void addNote(Notes newNote) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        session.merge(newNote);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //mal manejo, imprime el stacktrace completo
        //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        transaction.rollback();
    }
    session.close();
}
```